Windows critical process died after installing Ubuntu on an external SSD
I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 as dual boot to an external SSD, however I cannot boot Windows. The error is critical process died.
I am able to see files on the Windows disk on Ubuntu. The disk ADATA (240GB) is the disk where Windows is installed.


see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1518447/1698042
